# converting list to dict and averaging the values of duplicates in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list:

```
list = [(a,1),(b,2),(a,3)]
```

I want to convert it to a dict where when there is a duplicate (eg. `(a,1)` and `(a,3)`), it will be get the average so dict will just have 1 key:value pair which would be in this case `a:2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
l = [('a',1),('b',2),('a',3)]
d = defaultdict(list)
for pair in l:
    d[pair[0]].append(pair[1]) #add each number in to the list with under the correct key
for (k,v) in d.items():
    d[k] = sum(d[k])/len(d[k]) #re-assign the value associated with key k as the sum of the elements in the list divided by its length
```

So

```
print(d)
>>> defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': 2, 'b': 2})
```

Or even nicer and producing a plain dictionary in the end:

```
from collections import defaultdict
l = [('a',1),('b',2),('a',3)]
temp_d = defaultdict(list)
for pair in l:
    temp_d[pair[0]].append(pair[1])
#CHANGES HERE
final = dict((k,sum(v)/len(v)) for k,v in temp_d.items())
print(final)
>>> 
{'a': 2, 'b': 2}
```

Note that if you are using 2.x (as you are, you will need to adjust the following to force float division):

```
(k,sum(v)/float(len(v)))
```

OR

```
sum(d[k])/float(len(d[k]))
```

Comment: Or, simply add `from __future__ import division` at the top.

Comment: thanks. I'll try it out as the actual list is a lot longer than my sample 3 element list. let you know how it goes